# Python pip packages installation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have both python 2.7 and python 3.5.2 installed, both open IDLE just fine, my question is, if I go into the Cmd on Windows and type python it goes for the 2.7 version, how do I set it up so I have something like python2 and python3?

And finnally if i run python pip install *package* how do I know if it's installing for python 2.7 or 3.5.2.

Comment: on Linux we have `pip2` and `pip3` to install for different version but if you will have `python2` and `python3` then you can do `python3 -m pip install ...` to install for Python 3

Comment: you can create `python2.bat` with full path to Python2  python.exe. `python3.bat` with full path to Python3  python.exe. And put both `.bat` in folder which is in `PATH` variable.

Comment: @furas tried that says it can't find the command python3

Comment: use full path to python.exe - `C:/full_path_to_folder_with_python_3/python.exe`. And `python3.bat` has to be in folder which is in `PATH` variable - or add own folder to `PATH` - ie. `C:/batch` - and then put `python3.bat` in `C:/batch`. BTW: I don't use Windows any more so I can't test it if it still can works (it worked many years ago).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Python Launcher](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#launcher) in Windows CMD.

- Execute script:

  ```
  py -2.7 path_to_my_script.py
  ```

  or:

  ```
  py -3.5 path_to_my_script.py
  ```
- You can use `pip` the same way:

  ```
  py -2.7 -m pip install numpy
  ```

  for install NumPy in Python 2.7 or:

  ```
  py -3.5 -m pip install numpy
  ```

  for install NumPy in Python 3.5

Comment: This works like a charm, thank you, way easier than chaging PATH variables. +1

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `pip`, use `pip2` when targeting Python 2, and `pip3` for Python 3.

Windows does have these `pip2` and `pip3` version-specialized commands.

If you already installed a package and want to know what Python version of the package you installed, run an interpreter and import it.

```
python2
>>> import package
ImportError: No module named 'package'

python3
>>> import package
>>>
```